# Best places to put pre-processing JS code in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-animations

I came across a best practise question I cannot solve by myself:

Imagine I have a pre-processing code (literally two JS functions) where I readout existing CSS3 keyframe rules from the DOM and build some DOM elements according to them. The purpose is to build a timeline from a CSS3 keyframe animation.

My initial idea was to use a directive and so I put the pre-processor code in its linking function. The thing is that the pre-processor only have to run once and based on its result the timeline DOM should be constructed, so the directive feels a bit too much.

My second attempt was to use a directive controller and persist the results of my preprocessor there, eg. $scope.keyframeRules, $scope.animLength etc…. Yet it felt wrong to have this logical JS-code in a controller.

To explain what the pre-process function does:

function getKeyframeRules( keyframeName, document ) returns CSSOM object

Any suggestions would be really great!

Comment: You could manually bootstrap angular. Do that you need pre... then call angular.bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap is no option, as the keyframes are extracted live from another element.
The key question is: Where would I put this code so that it logically fit in.